# Get two records per user id sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am getting data

```
1 34 abc5
1 24 abc3
1 12 abc2
1 24 abc1
1 34 abc6
1 34 abc76
1 24 ab1c243
1 24 abc243
1 34 abc243
1 34 abc243
```

from my query .. is there any way to get output like this

my query

```
SELECT * FROM table2
WHERE (abc2 IN  (SELECT * FROM table3 AS f INNER JOIN
table1 AS u ON u.id_usr = f.userLogedin_id
WHERE      (u.id_usr = '13'))) AND (publish_status = '3')
ORDER BY guser_ID

1 34 abc5
1 34 abc6
1 24 abc3
1 24 abc1
1 12 abc2
```

i.e. orderby desc and limit to 2 per unique user .. in this case 34, 24 and 12 are unique user

Comment: could we see your query? Also, column heading can help, too ;)

Comment: added my query plz chk

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
with cte as
(
select row_number() over (partition by <col2> order by <col2> desc) as id, col1,col2,col3 from <tablename>
)
select * from cte where id<=2
```

Comment: change your order by also to <col2> since user needs records with highest col2 value

Comment: Also mention you can use this is SQL 2005 and above

Comment: @Vaibs_Cool - really? Surely you could edit the **<col2>** parts to what you want. I believe what Anand means by *col1, col2, col3* is the column names from thethree columns you given us. **<tablename>** will be your tables name?. Also, just to mention, your 'variables' aren't exactly the clearest in the world, so you might want to provide the table headings as well ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (id int,value int,name varchar(10))
insert into @t (id,value,name)values (1,34,'abc5')
insert into @t (id,value,name)values (1,24,'abc3')
insert into @t (id,value,name)values (1,12,'abc2')
insert into @t (id,value,name)values (1,24,'abc1')
insert into @t (id,value,name)values (1,34,'abc6')
insert into @t (id,value,name)values (1,34,'abc76')
insert into @t (id,value,name)values (1,24,'ab1c243')
insert into @t (id,value,name)values (1,24,'abc243')
insert into @t (id,value,name)values (1,34,'abc243')
insert into @t (id,value,name)values (1,34,'abc243')

SELECT  t.*
FROM    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT value
        FROM    @t
        ) tt
CROSS APPLY
        (
        SELECT  TOP 2 *
        FROM    @t t
        WHERE   t.value = tt.value
        ORDER BY
                1 DESC
        ) t
```